# Python-pptx - How to insert a slide number for all slides

Tags: python, automation, powerpoint, pywin32, python-pptx

I am trying to automatically insert slide numbers to all my slides in PPT that is messy and strictly formatted. When we do manually,we are not able to do it for all the PPTs due to manual work involved. Is there anyway to do this for all 35 plus slides in 20 plus PPT files? When we do using python inbuilt option menus ,it is not working and qe are unable to figure out why. Could be because of our messy format. So, want to use python pptx, insert text box and number them

I referred the SO post and tried the below

```
i=0
for slide in slides
    i = i + 1
    txBox = slide.shapes.add_textbox(0,0,10,12)
    tf = txBox.text_frame
    tf.text = i
    tf.font.size = (11)
```

But not sure whether am doing it right. How can I make the slide numbers appear at the bottom of slide?

**update based on Luke answer**

```
for slide in presentation.slides:
    i = i + 1
    txBox = slide.shapes.add_textbox(0,0,5,6)
    txBox.height = Inches(0.5)
    txBox.width = Inches(0.5)
    txBox.top = SH - txBox.height
    #if (i % 2) != 0:
    #    txBox.left = SW - Inches(OutsideMargin) - txBox.width
    #else:
    #    
    txBox.right = Inches(float(OutsideMargin)) #updated here
    tf = txBox.text_frame
    tf.vertical_anchor = MSO_ANCHOR.MIDDLE
    p = tf.paragraphs[0]
    p.alignment = PP_ALIGN.RIGHT  #updated here
    run = p.add_run()
    run.text = "Page" + str(i)
    run.font.size = Pt(11)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The slide number is usually put on a slide through a slide-number-placeholder on the slide-master or slide-layout. Those get then 'inherited' by the slide that is always based on a slide-layout which in turn is always based on a slide-master. BUT... one can remove any such inherited placeholder on a slide or layout. Thus the slide-no-placeholder where probably removed from your slides/layouts and therefore don't show up on the slides anymore. Therefore - I guess - using Luke's answer to put a new textbox everywhere is the best way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE

If you want the textbox to always be on the right side just do this

```
txBox.left = presentation.slide_width - txBox.width
```

You just need to reposition the textbox. maybe something like this...

```
from pptx import *
from pptx.util import Inches, Pt
from pptx.enum.text import MSO_ANCHOR, MSO_AUTO_SIZE, PP_ALIGN

presentation = Presentation("input.pptx")
SH = presentation.slide_height
SW = presentation.slide_width

OutsideMargin = 0.5

i=0
for slide in presentation.slides:
    i = i + 1
    txBox = slide.shapes.add_textbox(0,0,10,12)
    txBox.height = Inches(1)
    txBox.width = Inches(2)
    txBox.top = SH - txBox.height
    if (i % 2) != 0:
        txBox.left = SW - Inches(OutsideMargin) - txBox.width
    else:
        txBox.left = Inches(float(OutsideMargin))
    tf = txBox.text_frame
    tf.vertical_anchor = MSO_ANCHOR.MIDDLE
    p = tf.paragraphs[0]
    p.alignment = PP_ALIGN.CENTER
    run = p.add_run()
    run.text = "Page " + str(i)
    run.font.size = Pt(11)

presentation.save("output.pptx")
```

Comment: nice. upvoted. but one slight issue. For some slides the page number is on right side (of the slide) and for some slides it in on left side (of the slide). Is there anyway to fix that? would really be grateful if you can help me with it

Comment: I modified the `PP_ALIGN.CENTER` to `PP_ALIGN.RIGHT` but it doesn't put them in right side unfirmly for all slides

Comment: I also pasted the code (see my post above) that I tweaked (slightly for alignment) and also the screenshot.

Comment: Oh just changing the `outside margin` value worked for me. Is that all?

Comment: The outside margin is the distance from the outside of the slide. Do you want them fixed in a position e.g. the middle?

Comment: No, i want my slide numbet to appear at the right botyom of the screen. How can i do that?

Comment: See my updated answer regarding having the page number on the right side.

The if clause places the number on the right-hand side if the page number is odd, on the left side if the page number is even (minus any margin)

Comment: If your update line is responsible right alignment of text box, can I know what does this line do? - `txBox = slide.shapes.add_textbox(5,5,5,6)` because it has left, right, length, width etc

Comment: I see that if I want to push the slide number to a bit top of the slide (instead of right bottom), I had to use the `height` and `width` of text box. Can't we put a small text box in right middle of the side (instead of bottom right now) through coordinates (like nmeric values) instead of your formula? So, I can pay around with numbers and find out where I want them exactly

Comment: You can see my updated screenshot in post (at the bottom). Can let me know which values should I modify in your code to get the slide numbers there? my text box height and width is `0.3` and `0.3`. Instead of a formula, can you show me the number based approach?

Comment: txBox = slide.shapes.add_textbox(left, top, width, height) places the textbox at X amount from the left margin, X amount from the top, your width, your height

It's just an initial placement of the textbox I then manipulate the textbox later on in the code to whatever size/position I want.

Comment: If you want to adjust the positioning vertically you'd need to adjust this line

txBox.top = SH - txBox.height

This sets the top of the textbox to start at the slide height minus the height of the textbox and thus it appears at the very bottom. To move the textbox upwards simply subtract further from this e.g. txBox.top = (SH - txBox.height) - Inches(1)

would move the textbox up one inch

Comment: To have it on the left side you should do txBox.left = 0 

and to centre it you should do

txBox.left = (SW - txBox.width) / 2